# Deformation When I Apply Bevel Modifier

Tags: mesh, bevel

When I apply bevel modifier I get this deformation. Why is this?[image]

Comment: hello, please share the object (before you apply the bevel modifier): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BWo219p7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology is bad, it creates bevels where you are not expecting bevels, therefore overlapping faces. You need to create a good topology, with quads and not ngons:

[image]

[image]